# Best way to design functionality to automatically log users in who clicked on an email link

Tags: email, authentication, web

I have a hiking site and after a hike happens I generate an email to ask them how it was.

The current problem is that there is a low ratio of people signing in to tell about their hikes.  So I want to log them in automatically when they click on the link.  Since it will be from their email, I can rely that it is them, right? :)

I am thinking to have some GUID generated and if a person clicks through on the url that has the guid as a param, I can log them in.

Is that a good approach?  Is there something better that can be done?
Should I create the GUID as I am generating their email?  Or should I create the GUID right after they initially register for the hike?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way was to insert the guid whenever inserting the record that will be used later.

That way more things are inserted in one statement rather than updating that database record later.